# HTACCESS - Exclude certain domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have rewrite cond which goes like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bamse\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bamse.ba/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have found that code  on internet somewhere i have not written my self. 
What it does it redirects all my subdomains like www.bamse.ba, hello.bamse.ba to bamse.ba.

Fair enought. That is working fine as it's supposed to but the problem is im using timthumb.php scripts and it loads all images from images.anka.com

Problem now is if i enable that rewrite rule all my images are loaded from bamse.ba instead of images.anka.com

How can i excluded that domain images.anka.com it's not being part of that rewrite rule. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, strictly speaking, already in your question. If you look at the first `RewriteCond`, you'll notice that it compares `%{HTTP_HOST}` to `!^bamse\.ba$`. The `!` negates the result, so this part is only true if `%{HTTP_HOST}` is *not* equal to `bamse.ba`. That sounds really similar to what we want to accomplish here. To exclude `images.bamse.ba` too, we just need to add another `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images\.bamse\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bamse\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bamse.ba/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You might need to clear your cache before any changes are visible. Permanent redirects like this one can be cached by browsers for efficiency purposes, skipping one or more requests to the server.

Comment: Also `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^(images\.)?bamse\.ba$ [NC]` to combine the two RewriteCond's.

Comment: Thanx worked like a charm.. My final solution was:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images\.anka\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bamse\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bamse.ba/$1 [R=301,L]